# Xamarin.Forms: Button in TabbedPage

Tags: button, xamarin, tabbedpage

How to add button to other page on this code (this is part of one card in TabbedPage):

```
this.Children.Add(new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "Text",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = 20,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Children =
                {
                    new Image
                    {
                        Source = ImageSource.FromFile("image.png")
                    },
                    new Label
                    {
                        TextColor = Color.FromHex("#5F5A5A"),
                        FontSize = 16,
                        Text = "Other text"  
                    }
             }
            }
        });
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your issue right, you just need button in another tab?

```
this.Children.Add(new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "Text",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = 20,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Children =
                {
                    new Image
                    {
                        Source = ImageSource.FromFile("image.png")
                    },
                    new Label
                    {
                        TextColor = Color.FromHex("#5F5A5A"),
                        FontSize = 16,
                        Text = "Other text"  
                    }
             }
            }
        });
this.Children.Add(new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "Button",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
Children ={
              new Button{
Image = ImageSource.FromFile("button.png"),
Backgroundcolor = "Transparent"

}
             }
            }
        });
```

Alternatively you can use tap gesture recognizer

```
var button = new Image {  }; 
button.GestureRecognizers.Add (new TapGestureRecognizer (sender => {

}));
```

Comment: Just set Image property of the button to desired image and background color to transparent. See edits

Comment: the first code is not working / ImageSource.FromFile can't be implicity in xamarin.forms

Comment: Try the property `icon`. Documentation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/tabbed-page/